# Pass -metadata tags to FFMPEG as variables

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to generate multiple metadata tags for an FFMPEG command (in bash), but for some reason, FFMPEG is splitting my quoted strings into separate arguments, causing it to error out.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flac -acodec libmp3lame -metadata artist="my cool band" outfile.mp3
```

and

```
BAND='my cool band'
ffmpeg -i infile.flac -acodec libmp3lame -metadata artist="$BAND" outfile.mp3
```

Both work as anticipated. An mp3 copy of the flac is generated with "my cool band" as the artist metadata.

However,

```
METADATA='-metadata artist="my cool band"'
ffmpeg -i infile.flac -acodec libmp3lame $METADATA outfile.mp3
```

throws the error

```
[NULL @ 0x5634ee2ef1e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'cool'
cool: Invalid argument
```

I want to be able to scale this up so that METADATA contains *all* of the metadata for my file (extracted from a json file or similar)

Comment: I figured out a stopgap by hacking IFS, but boy, do I not like it!

I can set
IFS=$'\n\t'
And then rewrite the command so that everything except for the text portion of my metadata is tab or newline delimited. It involves a couple extra regexes, and it means I'm suddenly mixing spaces and tabs in my code.

Not my favorite solution, but I've been at this for hours and need to sleep

Comment: Try: `METADATA=('-metadata' 'artist=my cool band'); ffmpeg -i infile.flac -acodec libmp3lame "${METADATA[@]}" outfile.mp3`.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1529226/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `bash`, `$METADATA` is expanded first, and then split on the spaces. If you had written `"$METADATA"`, or had used `zsh`, it would have worked in the way you intended.